# What would be the best practice downloading all the files from a directory using Sftp

Tags: sftp, spring-integration

I would like to implement the following functionality:

1. downloading all the files from a specified remote directory to a local directory.
2. after downloading all the files I need a list file which contains all the downloaded files.
   (I only want this list file when all the files were downloaded successfully.)

Point 1: 
Let's say we have around 10 files in the remote directory.
I can use an `int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter` component to download all the files but 10 poll cycles are needed to download all of them since the inbound component is only able to download 1 file per poll request.
Spring Integration creates 10 File messages one by one.

Questions:

1. How can I identify the last file (message) received from the FTP server?
2. I don't want let users access to list file till all the files from the FTP is successfully received.
   How can I achive this? 
   I can write file names into a list file using the int-file:outbound-channel-adapter but users can read temorary information from that file before the download process is finished.
3. How can I trigger the event that all files which are on the FTP are downloaded?

Thanks for your advices

Ferenc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this isn't correct:

> the inbound component is only able to download 1 file per poll request

You can configure it to to download infinitely during the single poll - `max-messages-per-poll=-1`. Anyway it is a default option on `<poller>`.

Anyway if it is your case to dowload one file per poll, you can go ahead with that requirements.

Since any Messaging system tries to achieve `stateless` paradigm, it is normal that one message doesn't know anything about another. And with that they all don't impact each other. The `async` scenario is the best for Messaging. With that we can process the second message quicker, than the first one.

Your requirement is enough interest and I won't dare to call it strange. Because any business may have place.

Since you are going to process several download files as one group, there will be need to have some `marker` on the remote server. Or it can be some `timeframe`, which we can extract from file `timestamp`. Or there will be need to store on the remote server some marker file to point that a set of files are finished and you can process them from your application using their local version. Would be great, if that marker file can contain a list of file names of that group.

Otherwise we don't have any hook to `group` messages for those files.

From other side you can consider to use `<int-sftp:outbound-gateway>` with `MGET` command: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-outbound-gateway

Comment: The currently implemented solution executes ls command on the remote FTP server by using the int-sftp:outbound-gateway to be able to process FTP files in one group. And then I split the list and download them one by one and at the end of process files are removed from the FTP. But there is a disadvantage of this solution. The outbound-gateway component does not support polling. So I  had to use external scheduling to use this solution which is a little bit ugly for me.

Comment: Actually, it's OK. You can achieve the `outbound-gateway` `polling` scenario with fake `<inbound-channel-adapter expression="''">` and send that empty String Message to the `request-channel` of that SFTP gateway.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was a good tip to avoid external scheduling.